# Storyboard IB Designables Failed to update autolayout status Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I opened my project in Xcode 9 Beta and then again opening same in Xcode 8.3.2 I am getting this issue.

```
Failed to update auto layout status: Failed to launch designables agent. Check the console for a more detailed description and please file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com.
```

And Storyboard screen is like this.[image: Storyboard screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I opened my project in Xcode 9 Beta and then again opening same in Xcode 8.3.2 I am getting this issue.

That's a bug in a Xcode 9 beta as far as I know. I used to use Xcode 9 beta before and it messes up indeed my storyboard and xib layouts, not really messes up the layout itself, but the preview. Basically the whole interface builder.

Should you encounter that again, you know the drill in Xcode (any version):

1. Cmd+Shift+K
2. Cmd+AltOption+Shift+K
3. Restart Xcode

More info: When the Xcode 9 was still in beta, that happened to me a lot of times! I just avoided using that version and switched to Xcode 8.x for the meantime if I don't need to make a build to my iPhone 7plus with iOS 11 beta.

Solution for that: Download the Xcode 9 from the App Store.

Comment: @glenn clean the build folder worked it worked thanks, I will download stable Xcode 9 from store

Comment: The issue is in Xcode 9.1 as well. Can't believe clean and restart fixed it.

Comment: IKR. :) Haven't experienced such issue in the latest Xcode release :) This happened to me many times ONLY in beta version. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I was having XCode 9 and I opened an old project.
The problem was resolved when I changed the target in StoryBoard from iPhone 8 to iPhone SE.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you